# How to invalidate all providers created using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Assuming that we have created many providers (more than 30 for example) which work in different parts of our application.

Now the user decides to logout his account and we want to invalidate all these providers while pressing on logout button. I know that the common way is to use 'invalidate()' method on all these providers. It's a bit long for me.

And as far I know, we can use the autoDispose() while defining the providers, but this process doesn't seem to invalidate the providers; it simply resets them to their default value.

So, what I want to know: Is there any simple way to invalidate all these providers at the same time without having to make them invalidate one by one using 'invalidate()'?

I have already tried AutoDispose and Invalidate().

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have a provider that has the current user... for example a Stream provider that is watching Firebase's `authStateChanges`.  Then, for every provider that must be invalidated on logout or user changed, include `ref.watch(thatProvider)` even if you don't need the value.

This will ensure that every dependent provider will get at least invalidated, and if being listened or watched, will also get rebuilt.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong : What you are trying to say is to create a global user provider. Then in this global provider, I will paste a watch of all the others dependent providers. And in this way, when I will simply invalidate() the global one, it should invalidate his child. Am I right ?

Comment: Nope.  You have it backwards.  You should be thinking reactively instead of imperatively.   There's one source of truth for "who is logged in" (nullable if logged out).  EVERYTHING that depends on that value should be ref.watch *getting* that value.  Then, if that value changes (new user or logout), ALL the others automatically invalidate or rebuild if currently being watched.